# Subfield on Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some basic documents which look this format:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "",
        "city": "Paris",
        "countryCode": "FR"
    },
    "searchInCountry: false
}
```

And I'm doing a simple query, which if I'm right should give me my documents if `searchInCountry` is `false` OR if `address.countryCode` is `FR`:

```
POST /myDoc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term": {"searchInCountry": false} },
        { "term": {"address.countryCode": "FR"} }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the term on `address.countryCode` does not work. It never return me value even if `address.countryCode == FR`

For example, I have :

- One document with `searchInCountry` to `false` and `address.countryCode` to `DE`
- One document with `searchInCountry` to `true` and `address.countryCode` to `FR`

The query above will only return me the first one, because `searchInCountry` is `false`, but not the second one whereas `address.countryCode` match `FR`

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.1, I don't know if it can be related (it's an old production server)

**UPDATE**

My mapping:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "myDoc":{
            "properties":{
                "firstName":{
                    "type":"text"
                },
                "lastName":{
                    "type":"text"
                },
                "searchInCountry":{
                    "type":"boolean"
                },
                "address":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "city":{
                            "type":"keyword"
                        },
                        "countryCode":{
                            "type":"text"
                        },
                        "street":{
                            "type":"text"
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested also with nested, but the issue is the same:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "address",
            "query": {
              "term": { "address.countryCode": {"value": "FR"} }
            }
          }
        },
        { "term": {"searchInCountry": false} }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 & solution:**

nested was required, but I also needed to change from `term` to `match` because my mapping was `text` and not `keyword`. Thanks @saeednasehi for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have nested object you need to define a path for your search. Your query might be something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "address",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "address.countryCode": {
                  "value": "FR"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "searchInCountry": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also tested it after seen it on others answers in SO, but the issue is the same : https://i.imgur.com/j4SfZQx.png  - https://i.imgur.com/esAEEB4.png

Comment: Could you please add your mapping here?

Comment: countryCode type is `text`. It is better for you to set it `keyword`.

Comment: Hum, yes, that was the issue.
Do avoid me changing my field mapping, I tested with match instead of term and it's working well!
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Yes, in `text` types match works! but the best type for this purpose is `keyword`. match by default uses more Heap in comparison with term. However good to have your issue solved. You're welcome.